# Why is there no Swift equivalent for adding an action to a view?

Tags: swift

Looking around Stack Overflow, you will find dozens of resources on how to add an action to a button, adding an action to a view, and so forth. Each of these resources use `@objc`, because `#selectors` is `objc` code. But, not a single resource I can find, adds an action to a view without using `objc`. 
Marking something as `objc` exposes it to `Objective-C` run-time, necessary when using Selectors.

Essentially, it comes down to these questions:

- Is it possible to create an action without using `@objc` code?

  - If so, why are so many resources using `@objc` code for actions?
- If it is not possible, why has nothing been done yet?

  - Why have we reached Swift, Version 4, without a `Swift` equivalent for adding actions to a view?
  - Will there be a future update that implements a `Swift` variation for adding actions to a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target/selector mechanism is how `UIControl` (and similar classes) was written long ago, in Objective-C, before even Objective-C blocks were a thing.

Your question is just as valid for Objective-C. Why doesn't `UIControl` (and similar) provide a block based API instead of the dated target/selector pattern?

So it's not a matter of updating Swift. It's a question of adding a block/closure based API to relevant classes that use the target/selector pattern.

If you do a little searching on GitHub you will find a closure based Swift API that actually does what you want. Of course, its implementation is to use the old target/selector APIs.