# Swift - Is it possible to avoid selector when handling tap events?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I had some experiences in React Native, which handles button press event like this:

```
onPressButton = () => {console.log('Hello')}

render() {
  return (
    <Button onPress={this.onPressButton} />
  );
}
```

Coming into swift world, I found it frustrating to deal with the "Selector pattern".

```
@objc func onPressButton() {print("Hello")}

UIBarButtonItem(title: "Detail", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.onPressButton))
```

I think using `@objc` and `#selector()` is really ugly. Is this pattern essential for dealing with "button press" event? It there any way to avoid it?

(I have seen someone writing some extensions to use closure, but I would like see something supported by swift natively)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005654/why-is-there-no-swift-equivalent-for-adding-an-action-to-a-view/51005698#51005698

Comment: It's possible: 
https://medium.com/@BeauNouvelle/adding-a-closure-to-uibarbuttonitem-24dfc217fe72